# Sending raw binary data via AJAX as BLOB

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest, binary-data

I am trying to send binary data via blob... but it doesn't seem to be the same as when I base64 it before sending... Seems that somehow it is being converted from UTF8 to UTF16 in flight... or something...

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://...:P', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { alert('ok'); };

  // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

upload(new Blob([binary_data_string], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}));
```

What exactly am I missing / doing wrong?

**Real example**

1. [good.dat](http://creation.pl/good.dat)  - data received when sending it Base64 encoded and decoding via PHP - a good one.
2. [bad.dat](http://creation.pl/bad.dat)  - data received when it was sent without Base64 encoding - bad one.

Comment: use processData to false:

Comment: processData is jQuery option, in my case it's pure javascript

Comment: oops ,, then use this xhr.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");

Comment: nah... that did not change a thing... even when I set charset to UTF8, it still sends it as UTF16. How do I know? Well.. file size is exactly 1.5x of good one.

Comment: Try this too .. Force content type to be null .. xhr.setRequestHeader('"Content-Type", '')

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest — scroll to vanilla example :: sendAsBinary.